# Trying to add image for menu items

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

These are menu items. Please note that I'm giving the image class to the City menu item.

```
<p:submenu label="Address">
    <p:menuitem value="Country" url="/secured/country.xhtml?redirect=true" />
    <p:menuitem value="State" url="/secured/state.xhtml?redirect=true" />
    <p:menuitem value="City" url="/secured/city.xhtml?redirect=true" icon="images"/>                          
    <p:menuitem value="Location" url="/secured/location.xhtml?redirect=true" />
</p:submenu>
```

This is my CSS class:

```
 .images{
     background: url('../resources/images/admini.ico') no-repeat;
     height:16px;
     width:16px;
}
```

However, instead of an image appearing, an upward-facing arrow mark appears. How can I fix this?

Comment: try to use some *png* file instead of the *ico* , also know that you can use these icons http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.6rc5/tests/static/icons.html (click on Toggle text to get all the names of the icons)

Comment: @Daniel tried with .png image but result was, showing this symbol' ^ ' instead of an image

Comment: @Daniel I want use image-set of my own

Comment: try to use `styleClass="images"` instead of `icon`

Answer (score 0):

try to define your icon as following

```
.ui-menuitem-icon.images{
     background: url('../resources/images/someImage.png') no-repeat;
     height:16px;
     width:16px;
}
```

and take a look at this thread [How do you add a custom icon to a menuitem?](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23462)

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
      .tabmenubutton
        {
         background:url("common/images/calendar.png") no-repeat !important;
         width:20px;
         height:20px;
        }
```

xhtml:

```
      <p:menuitem value="Country" icon="tabmenubutton"/>
```